# Please help! Don’t know what this word is

Tags: word-request

please help!
I need some advise 
How would I say 2 000 000 000 000 000?
If you do know please say

Comment: What research have you done toward finding the answer on your own? This is easily answerable with resources available on the internet.

Comment: Google "2 000 000 000 000 000" and click the first result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [long scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Long_scale), that number is "two thousand billion" or "two billiard". If you are using the [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Short_scale), it is "two quadrillion".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's two quadrillion. [(Short scale, used by *most* English speakers.)](https://www.thoughtco.com/zeros-in-million-billion-trillion-2312346)

Comment: Quadrillion has 24 zeros, OP's example only has 15 zeros.

Comment: That site says a quadrillion has 5 sets of 3 zeroes.

Comment: http://www.math.com/tables/general/numnotation.htm as does this site and multiple others. Number with 15 zeroes.

Comment: Both you and @Peter should see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales, and clarify your "disagreement"

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I saw your answer. I read the article you posted as well. It says the short system is used in most English speaking countries, which in my humble opinion makes my answer correct.

Comment: @Element115 - I am not suggesting that either of you is _wrong_, but your respective comments looked like you both were about to 'get into it' over the difference, and (based on the link I posted in my answer), you're actually both correct, depending on context.

Comment: Fair enough. I upvoted your answer because it was more complete than any of ours.

Answer (score 0):

That would be

> **two billiard** *(long scale)*

or

> **two quadrillion**  *(short scale, AmE, BrE)*

or

> **two Peta** *(metric)*

Please refer to [Order of Magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)

Comment: Both you and @Element115 should see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales, and clarify your "disagreement"

Comment: As regards 'metric', those are the SI _prefixes_; they normally don't stand alone - e.g., two billiard meters would be "two petameters".

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of **billion** was historically inconsistent. Now it is usually one thousand million but what would one make of a historical document?

I suggest that

> 2 000 000 000 000 000

be said as

> Two times ten to the fifteen

The number is so large, it is difficult to realise it, but my definition is unambiguous.

Comment: Good point. This number might be better reprsentated in scientific notation.